# Javascript split string by first instance of lowercase character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I would like to take Pascal string inputs and split them up by hyphens.

```
"HelloWorld" becomes "hello-world"
```

I'm able to do that no problem, however my regex attempts start to break down when say a person supplies the following:

```
"FAQ" becomes "f-a-q"
```

I want it to keep FAQ as "faq", so I think I need to be splitting the string up by all first instances of a lowercase vs uppercase correct?

My regex right now is:

```
name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the middle starting uppercase letters.

```js
function hyphenate(string) {
    return string.replace(/[^A-Z](?=[A-Z])/g, '$&-').toLowerCase();
}

console.log(hyphenate("FAQ"));        // faq
console.log(hyphenate("ReadTheFAQ")); // read-the-faq
console.log(hyphenate("HelloWorld")); // hello-world
```

Comment: Thank you!  This makes way more sense and allows me more room to play with further conditions as needed. I can't vote for your answer cause of rep, but this does solve my question above.

Comment: can you please run the regex on https://regex101.com/ because doesn't work in notepad++

Comment: what is the issue with it?

Comment: This works great. You don't know how long I spent trying to find the right RegEx pattern thank you!